# Alternative writing of null check between two variables?

Tags: java

I am having a bit of a conundrum.
I have 2 objects `A` and `B`.
They can come as `null` or not `null`, and I have to do some different business logic in all of those situations.

At the moment I have:

```
if(A != null && B != null) { /* operation1 */ } 
if(A == null && B == null) { /* operation2 */ }
if(A != null && B == null) { /* operation3 */ } 
if(A == null && B != null) { /* operation4 */ }
```

Can you recommend me a way of writing those `if`s in a more elegant way?

Comment: If you need to do 4 different things, short of using `else if`, or nesting `if (A != null) { if (B != null) { } }`, there is not really much else you can do.

Comment: Nesting if-else statements is in fact a code smell so you shouldn't do it. Switches are kind of the same with what you already have and anyway they don't apply to these kind of comparisons without complicating your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if you want to keep your if conditions visible in the calling method, your code is a better option than the solution proposed to imbricate the if conditions. All those if-else and inner if-else statements make it less obvious what the conditions are that trigger each operation. So you can keep your approach. See [this blog post from Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

One small improvement you can do is extract methods from the if conditions and name the new methods in a way that documents your decisions:

```java
if( isYouHaveACarAndEnoughGas(A, b)) { //operation to drive}
if( isYouHaveACarAndNoGas(A, b)) { //operation to walk}
...
private boolean isYouHaveACarAndEnoughGas(...){ return A != null && B != null; }
```

If you want/need something more fancy, you can use a command pattern or strategy. As a rule of thumb, repeated if-else statements or switches are signs you can use polymorphism to get the same result. See [this excellent post with examples](https://www.developer.com/java/data/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements.html).

```java
interface Operation{
    void execute();
}

class OperationBuilder {
    public static Operation build(TypeA A, TypeB B){
        if(A != null && B != null) { return new OperationOne(); }
        if(A == null && B == null) { return new OperationTwo(); }
        if(A != null && B == null) { /* operation3 */ }
        if(A == null && B != null) { /* operation4 */ }
    }

    class OperationOne implements Operation{
        private OperationOne(){...}
        @Override
        void execute(){...}
    }
    class OperationTwo implements Operation{
        private OperationTwo(){}
        @Override
        void execute(){...}
    }
}
```

To use this you just

```java
Operation op = OperationBuilder.build(A, B) ;
op.execute();
```

And here is **why this can be better than what you started of**. Imagine you have

```
if(codition1){
  //complicated stuff here that makes you scroll and scroll
}
if(codition2){
  //complicated stuff here that makes you scroll and scroll
}
etc
```

You are likely to not see all the conditions on the same screen so you lose the overview of what's going on. On the other hand, the builder keeps all the conditions tight and clean, while the operational logic is again separated from noise.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid checking the same condition multiple times:

```
if (A != null) {
    if (B != null) {
        // operation1
    } else {
        // operation3
    }
} else {
    if (B != null) {
        // operation4
    } else {
        // operation2
    }
}
```

But that doesn't really make the code look more elegant.

Comment: This style makes it harder to read the conditions. Ask yourself under what conditions do you do operation 2, for eg, and you end up doing some mental operations that are prone to error

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, although it's debatable whether it's better or worse than what you already have (which is not bad):

```
switch ((A == null ? 0 : 10) + (B == null ? 0 : 1)) {
    case 00:
        operation 1...
        break;
    case 01:
        operation 2...
        break;
    case 10:
        operation 3...
        break;
    case 11:
        operation 4...
        break;
    default:
        throw new AssertionError("This can't happen.");
}
```

Comment: It is a nice hack but in fact it adds complexity to the code: so it will be harder to understand the code and more effort to make sure it doesn't break. So I wouldn't do it

Comment: Note that the numbers `00`, `01` , `10` and `11` look like binary numbers, but they are actually octal and decimal numbers. Why not use real binary numbers, by prefixing them with `0b`? `0b00`, `0b01`, `0b10`, `0b11`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the equivalent solution using nested if/else:

```
if(A != null)
{
    if(B != null)
    {
        /* operation1 */
    }
    else
    {
        /* operation3 */
    }
}
else
{
    if(B != null)
    {
        /* operation4 */
    }
    else
    {
        /* operation2 */
    }
}
```

As you can clearly see, the semantics of "do xyz if a...b...c... conditions hold" is a lot less clear with this approach. Therefore, the "inelegant" approach you propose is in fact a logical and clear piece of code. At best, you can do something like the following:

```
// Using a helper class with method names that 
// clearly communicate intent/meaning in the null checks:
class Logics
{
    public static boolean allNull(Object... objs)
    {
        for(Object o : objs)
            if(o != null)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean noneNull(Object... objs)
    {
        for(Object o : objs)
            if(o == null)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
...
if(Logics.noneNull(A, B)) { /* operation1 */ } 
if(Logics.allNull(A, B)) { /* operation2 */ }
if(A != null && B == null) { /* operation3 */ } 
if(A == null && B != null) { /* operation4 */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this combined with [Jesper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117683/5525384) :

```
Predicate<Object> isNull = Objects::isNull; // or o -> o != null
Predicate<Object> isNotNull = Objects::nonNull; // or o -> o == null

if (isNull.test(A)) { 
    if (isNotNull.test(B)) {
        /* operation1 */ 
    }
    else {
        /* operation2 */
    }
}
else {
    if(isNull.test(B)) { 
        /* operation3 */ 
    }
    else {
        /* operation4 */ 
    }
}
```